# I'm using Primeng calendar for datepicker in Angular 7. I'm facing issue in while retrieving the data, its returning one day off

Tags: java, spring-boot, angular7, primeng-calendar

I'm passing the data to back-end in date format -

`Fri Nov 08 201900:00:00 GMT+0530` (India Standard Time) ,

but it was automatically
   converting the date format to this DateandTime format -
   `2019-11-07T18:30:00.000Z` and in database its storing `'2019-11-08'`.
   while retrieving the data it's returning one day off `'2019-11-07'`.

Comment: which database you are using and what is timezone of your database?

Comment: MySQL Database and timezone of my Database is EST.

Comment: Angular converts your date time according to the local time zone
Change your mysql time zone to UTC(co-ordinated universal time zone) and save your date again and check it. this will give you the correct output.
hope this helps you

Comment: I had changed the Mysql database timezone to SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+00:00'; but still its storing one day off. While passing in the API, its working as expected date. I don't know what to do?